# DirectX 11: Number of BOUND Shader Resource Views

Tags: directx-11

I have a management system for my shader resources which auto generates the HLSL header code for all of my shaders which looks something like:

```
   Texture2DArray <float4> MyTextureArray1 : register(t0)
   Texture2DArray <float4> MyTextureArray2 : register(t1)
   Texture2DArray <float4> MyTextureArray3 : register(t2)
   Texture2DArray <float4> MyTextureArray4 : register(t3)
```

The management system also automatically creates and binds all of the shader resource views at creation time. Obviously, my shaders use maybe 1 or 2 of these textures but I leave them all bound all the time. Can anyone speculate as to whether it is better for me to only bind the SRVs that I currently need and clear the others every time I bind a shader, or is it better to just bind all of the SRVs at creation time and never touch them again? I haven't found much documentation stating the overhead of leaving resources bound even though I'm not currently using them.

As a side note, in some of my projects I have 30 or 40 SRVs due to various formats, texture dimensions, and usages.

Which is better?

1) Bind all 128 and never change the bindings

2) Bind and unbind SRVs as needed when changing shaders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DX11 you can create thousands of SRVs. However you can bind 128 of those to each shader stage. As long as you don't use more than 128 SRVs per stage and you index them correctly in your HLSL code then you're good. Also take a look at [Direct3D 11 Resource Limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819065(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I know about the resource limits. Is there an overhead penalty with having lets say all 128 SRVs bound?

Which is better? 
1) Bind all 128 and never change the bindings
2) Bind and unbind SRVs as needed when changing shaders

Comment: When you bind an SRV, you're changing the pipeline state which has some performance penalty. If your scene has less than 128 different textures, then binding them all at once would be the better approach. Most games, however, bind different textures to the pipeline for each object that is being rendered. That is because in general more than 128 textures are used to render a scene.

Comment: The over 128 textures is where my management system comes it. It gathers textures for all objects in the scene and packs them into texture arrays and adjusts each object's shader. This greatly reduces the total number of buffers. I was still curious about the overhead of leaving these large buffers bound even if a shader wasn't going to access it. For example, one texture array has several high resolution height maps for terrain which stays bound when rendering everything else.